# How do I scale a container div after scaling contents?

Tags: css, html

I have a construct like the following:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="menu">--- mymenu ---</div>
    <div class="edit">--- myeditor ---</div>
</div>
```

The menu and edit classes are display:inline so they will sit side by side.

I give the user the option to 'scale' the editor (using css scale) but when I do, the content div remains the same height as the un-scaled edit div. The edit div has set width and height, bit is then modified with something like:

```
-webkit-transform:scale(1.25); 
-moz-transform:scale(1.25); 
-ms-transform:scale(1.25);
```

which works fine for scaling the edit div, but the content div won't scale to accommodate it. I can make the content div overflow:visible and that will show the contents of edit, but  overwrites anything below it on the page.

How can I get my content div to scale when I scale the edit div?